# extracting youtube playlist item ID's & duration (YouTube iFrame API)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, youtube

I've spent the last 3 days trying to build a video gallery using the YouTube iframe API, I've made some progress, I can load a video no problem, I can get the duration of that video and bind various events to it. I can also do this with multiple videos on a page.

However this is where I've run into trouble. I'm using the new bootstrap 4 carousel to house the iframe that plays the main video and below it I've got a handful of thumbnails that contain the other videos in any given playlist.

What I'm struggling with is accessing the playlist data before the players are created. Since I can't seem to access the cuePlaylist function without using e.target. And seeing as there are 10 players it means this is happening 10 times which just feels wrong!

What i'd like to do is as follows.

1. In the CMS, user adds the youtube playlist ID to a data attribute on the wrapping div of the video gallery.
2. From there, I take that playlist ID, retrieve the video ID's within and add them to an object I can reference later on.
3. Loop through my object, create players based on each ID and add them to the carousel list-items.
4. In the same loop, use getDuration() and calculate the total time of each video (to be displayed in the gallery).
5. Set up event listeners to ensure that no more than one video gets played at a time yadda yadda, that stuff is pretty straightforward.

Now I know the following code is wrong, but I've spent the last few days trying to refactor it, come at it from different angles, turn it upside down, inside out etc etc and I'm finally admitting defeat and asking you good people for some help!

```js
window.videoPlayer = (function($) {

    var model, player, videoArray, videoArrayObject,

        createPlayer = function(playerInfo) {
            player = new YT.Player(playerInfo.name, {
                playerVars: {
                    controls: 0,
                    iv_load_policy: 3, // Disables annotations.
                    showinfo: 0,
                    rel: 0,
                    cc_load_policy: 1,
                    modestbranding: 1,
                    playsinline: 1,
                    fs: 0,
                    enablejsapi: 1,
                    listType: 'playlist',
                    list: playerInfo.playlistID
                },
                events: {
                    "onReady": onReady,
                    "onStateChange": onPlayerStateChange,
                    "onError": onError
                }
            });
        },
    /**
     * play the targeted video (and hide the poster frame)
     * @param {object} e is event
     */
    videoPlay = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $el = $(e.currentTarget);
            var $wrapper = $el.closest(model.container);
            // hide poster
            $wrapper.addClass(model.videoWrapperActive);
            e.data.param.target.playVideo();
        },

    onReady = function(e) {
        $(model.container).removeClass('is-loading');
        var total;
        var vidDuration = 0;
        var parent = $(e.target.a).next();

        if (e == null) {
            return
        } else {
            total = e.target.getDuration();
            vidDuration = Math.floor(total / 60) + ":" + (total % 60 ? total % 60 : '00');
        }
        $(parent).find('.video-duration').html(vidDuration);

        $(model.videoPoster).click({param: e}, videoPlay);
    },

    onPlayerStateChange = function(e) {
        if (e.data === 0) {
            $(e.target.a).next().parent().removeClass(model.videoWrapperActive);
        }
    },

    goFullscreen = function(id) {

    },

    onError = function(e) {
        console.error('playback error');
    },

    /**
     * Init class to initiate script
     * @public
     * @param {object} args is from doc-ready init file
     */
    init = function(args) {
        args = args || {};
        model = {
            init: function() {
                this.container = args.container || '.video-wrapper';
                this.videoWrapperActive = args.videoWrapperActive || 'video-wrapper-active';
                this.videoDuration = args.videoDuration || '.video-duration';
                this.videoPoster = args.videoPoster || '.video-poster';
                this.playlistID = args.playlistID || $('.carousel-inner').attr('data-youTubePlaylistId');
            }
        };

        model.init();

        $.each($(model.container), function(i, container) {
            $(container).find('.video-player').attr('id', 'ytPlayer' + i);
        });

        videoArray = [];
        videoArrayObject = {};

        $.getScript('https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api');

        window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {

            $.each($(model.container), function(i, video) {
                videoArrayObject = {
                    name: $(video).find('.video-player').attr('id'),
                    id: $(video).attr("data-youTubeId"),
                    duration: '',
                    playlistID: model.playlistID
                };
                videoArray.push(videoArrayObject);
            });

            if (typeof videoArray === 'undefined')
                return;

            for (var i = 0; i < videoArray.length; i++) {
                var currentPlayer = createPlayer(videoArray[i]);
            }
        };
    };

    /**
     * Returns init
     * @return public methods/functions
     * @public
     */
    return {
        init: init
    };

}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- main slider carousel -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12" id="slider">
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
            <!-- main slider carousel items -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" data-youTubePlaylistId="PLRWIBpSyMDkowgqG8rvNF13GlhlmyPIki">
                <div class="active item carousel-item" data-slide-number="0">
                    <div class="video-wrapper is-loading" data-youTubeId="" vid-height="270" vid-width="480">
                        <div class="video-player" id=""></div>
                        <div class="video-poster" style="background-image:url('https://img.youtube.com/vi/WFpJnRvK6C4/maxresdefault.jpg')">
                            <div class="video-player-content">
                                <h2>Train For Tomorrow HD</h2>
                                <p class="video-duration"></p>
                                <a class="" href="#_">Play video</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="loading-div"></div>
                        <div class="playlist-wrapper">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item carousel-item" data-slide-number="1">
                    <div class="video-wrapper is-loading" data-youTubeId="" vid-height="270" vid-width="480">
                        <div class="video-player" id=""></div>
                        <div class="video-poster" style="background-image:url('https://img.youtube.com/vi/WFpJnRvK6C4/maxresdefault.jpg')">
                            <div class="video-player-content">
                                <h2>Train For Tomorrow HD</h2>
                                <p class="video-duration"></p>
                                <a class="" href="#_">Play video</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="loading-div"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item carousel-item" data-slide-number="2">
                    <div class="video-wrapper is-loading" data-youTubeId="" vid-height="270" vid-width="480">
                        <div class="video-player" id=""></div>
                        <div class="video-poster" style="background-image:url('https://img.youtube.com/vi/WFpJnRvK6C4/maxresdefault.jpg')">
                            <div class="video-player-content">
                                <h2>Train For Tomorrow HD</h2>
                                <p class="video-duration"></p>
                                <a class="" href="#_">Play video</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="loading-div"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item carousel-item" data-slide-number="3">
                    <div class="video-wrapper is-loading" data-youTubeId="" vid-height="270" vid-width="480">
                        <div class="video-player" id=""></div>
                        <div class="video-poster" style="background-image:url('https://img.youtube.com/vi/WFpJnRvK6C4/maxresdefault.jpg')">
                            <div class="video-player-content">
                                <h2>Train For Tomorrow HD</h2>
                                <p class="video-duration"></p>
                                <a class="" href="#_">Play video</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="loading-div"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item carousel-item" data-slide-number="4">
                    <div class="video-wrapper is-loading" data-youTubeId="" vid-height="270" vid-width="480">
                        <div class="video-player" id=""></div>
                        <div class="video-poster" style="background-image:url('https://img.youtube.com/vi/WFpJnRvK6C4/maxresdefault.jpg')">
                            <div class="video-player-content">
                                <h2>Train For Tomorrow HD</h2>
                                <p class="video-duration"></p>
                                <a class="" href="#_">Play video</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="loading-div"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item carousel-item" data-slide-number="5">
                    <div class="video-wrapper is-loading" data-youTubeId="" vid-height="270" vid-width="480">
                        <div class="video-player" id=""></div>
                        <div class="video-poster" style="background-image:url('https://img.youtube.com/vi/WFpJnRvK6C4/maxresdefault.jpg')">
                            <div class="video-player-content">
                                <h2>Train For Tomorrow HD</h2>
                                <p class="video-duration"></p>
                                <a class="" href="#_">Play video</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="loading-div"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item carousel-item" data-slide-number="6">
                    <div class="video-wrapper is-loading" data-youTubeId="" vid-height="270" vid-width="480">
                        <div class="video-player" id=""></div>
                        <div class="video-poster" style="background-image:url('https://img.youtube.com/vi/WFpJnRvK6C4/maxresdefault.jpg')">
                            <div class="video-player-content">
                                <h2>Train For Tomorrow HD</h2>
                                <p class="video-duration"></p>
                                <a class="" href="#_">Play video</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="loading-div"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item carousel-item" data-slide-number="7">
                    <div class="video-wrapper is-loading" data-youTubeId="" vid-height="270" vid-width="480">
                        <div class="video-player" id=""></div>
                        <div class="video-poster" style="background-image:url('https://img.youtube.com/vi/WFpJnRvK6C4/maxresdefault.jpg')">
                            <div class="video-player-content">
                                <h2>Train For Tomorrow HD</h2>
                                <p class="video-duration"></p>
                                <a class="" href="#_">Play video</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="loading-div"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- <a class="carousel-control left pt-3" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
                <a class="carousel-control right pt-3" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a> -->

            </div>
            <!-- main slider carousel nav controls -->


            <ul class="carousel-indicators list-inline">
                <li class="list-inline-item active">
                    <a id="carousel-selector-0" class="selected" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel">
                        <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/WFpJnRvK6C4/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="" class="video-poster">
                        <!-- <div class="video-poster" style="background-image:url('http://img.youtube.com/vi/WFpJnRvK6C4/maxresdefault.jpg')"> -->
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="list-inline-item">
                    <a id="carousel-selector-1" data-slide-to="1" data-target="#myCarousel">
                        <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/WFpJnRvK6C4/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="" class="video-poster">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="list-inline-item">
                    <a id="carousel-selector-2" data-slide-to="2" data-target="#myCarousel">
                        <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/WFpJnRvK6C4/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="" class="video-poster">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="list-inline-item">
                    <a id="carousel-selector-3" data-slide-to="3" data-target="#myCarousel">
                        <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/WFpJnRvK6C4/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="" class="video-poster">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="list-inline-item">
                    <a id="carousel-selector-4" data-slide-to="4" data-target="#myCarousel">
                        <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/WFpJnRvK6C4/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="" class="video-poster">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="list-inline-item">
                    <a id="carousel-selector-5" data-slide-to="5" data-target="#myCarousel">
                        <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/WFpJnRvK6C4/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="" class="video-poster">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="list-inline-item">
                    <a id="carousel-selector-6" data-slide-to="6" data-target="#myCarousel">
                        <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/WFpJnRvK6C4/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="" class="video-poster">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="list-inline-item">
                    <a id="carousel-selector-7" data-slide-to="7" data-target="#myCarousel">
                        <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/WFpJnRvK6C4/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="" class="video-poster">
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

---

EDIT: I spent all day today refactoring my code, I've managed to make some progress but still facing some challenges.

I've reached the point where I retrieve the playlist ID's and dynamically generate the carousel list items based on how many videos are retrieved. Those list items get the video ID's set correctly and all that works fine.

My next issue is that aside from the first video, I can't get the video duration for the rest of the videos, and when i try and play any aside from the first i get a playback error.

Here is the updated JS and HTML

```js
window.videoPlayer = (function($) {

    var model, player, videoArray, videoArrayObject, playListGet,

        createPlayer = function(playerInfo) {
            player = new YT.Player(playerInfo.name, {
                videoId: '',
                playerVars: {
                    controls: 0,
                    iv_load_policy: 3, // Disables annotations.
                    showinfo: 0,
                    rel: 0,
                    cc_load_policy: 1,
                    modestbranding: 1,
                    playsinline: 1,
                    fs: 0,
                    enablejsapi: 1,
                    listType: 'playlist',
                    list: playerInfo.playlistID
                },
                events: {
                    "onReady": preLoadPlaylist,
                    "onStateChange": onPlayerStateChange,
                    "onError": onError
                }
            });
        },

        preLoadPlaylist = function(e) {
            var playListCue = e.target.cuePlaylist({
                listType: 'playlist',
                list: model.playlistID
            });
        },

        onPlayerStateChange = function(e) {

            if (e.data == YT.PlayerState.CUED) {

                playListGet = e.target.getPlaylist();

                $.each(playListGet, function(i, playListItem) {

                    $(model.carousel).append(
                        '<div class="item carousel-item" data-slide-number="' + (i + 1) + '">' +
                        '<div class="video-wrapper is-loading" data-youTubeId="' + playListItem + '">' +
                        '<div class="video-player" id="ytPlayer' + (i + 1) + '"></div>' +
                        '<div class="video-poster" style="background-image:url(https://img.youtube.com/vi/' + playListItem + '/maxresdefault.jpg)">' + '<div class="video-player-content"><h2>VIDEO TITLE HERE</h2><p class="video-duration">VIDEO DURATION HERE</p><a class="" href="#_">Play video</a></div></div>' +
                        '<div class="loading-div"></div>'
                    );
                    $(model.carouselThumbnailWrapper).append(
                        '<li class="list-inline-item">' +
                        '<a id="carousel-selector-' + (i + 1) + '" class="selected" data-slide-to="' + (i + 1) + '" data-target="#myCarousel">' +
                        '<img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/' + playListItem + '/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="" class="video-poster"></a></li>'
                    );
                });

                $(model.carouselThumbnailWrapper).removeClass('hidden');
                onReady(e);

                $(model.carouselThumbnail).click({
                    param: e
                }, cueVideo);
            }
            if (e.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
                $(e.target.a).next().parent().removeClass(model.videoWrapperActive);
            }
        },

        cueVideo = function(e) {
            var total = e.data.param.target.getDuration();
            var vidDuration = Math.floor(total / 60) + ":" + (total % 60 ? total % 60 : '00');

            console.log(vidDuration);
            // e.data.param.target.cueVideoById();
            // console.log(e.data.param);
            onReady(e.data.param);
        },

        onReady = function(e) {
            console.log(e);
            var total;
            var vidDuration = 0;
            var parent = $(e.target.a).next();

            $(model.container).removeClass('is-loading');

            if (e == null) {
                return
            } else {
                total = e.target.getDuration();
                vidDuration = Math.floor(total / 60) + ":" + (total % 60 ? total % 60 : '00');
            }
            $(parent).find('.video-duration').html(vidDuration);

            $(model.videoPoster).click({
                param: e
            }, videoPlay);
        },

        /**
         * play the targeted video (and hide the poster frame)
         * @param {object} e is event
         */
        videoPlay = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $el = $(e.currentTarget);
            var $wrapper = $el.closest(model.container);
            // hide poster
            $wrapper.addClass(model.videoWrapperActive);
            console.log(e.data.param.target);
            e.data.param.target.playVideo();
        },

        goFullscreen = function(id) {

        },

        onError = function(e) {
            console.error('playback error');
        },

        /**
         * Init class to initiate script
         * @public
         * @param {object} args is from doc-ready init file
         */
        init = function(args) {
            args = args || {};
            model = {
                init: function() {
                    this.container = args.container || '.video-wrapper';
                    this.videoWrapperActive = args.videoWrapperActive || 'video-wrapper-active';
                    this.videoDuration = args.videoDuration || '.video-duration';
                    this.videoPoster = args.videoPoster || '.video-poster';
                    this.carousel = args.carousel || '.carousel-inner';
                    this.carouselThumbnailWrapper = args.carouselThumbnailWrapper || '.carousel-indicators';
                    this.carouselThumbnail = args.carouselThumbnail || '.list-inline-item';
                    this.videoID = args.videoID || $(model.container).attr('data-youTubeId');
                    this.playlistID = args.playlistID || $(model.carousel).attr('data-youTubePlaylistId');
                }
            };

            model.init();

            videoArray = [];
            videoArrayObject = {};

            $.getScript('https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api');

            window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {

                videoArrayObject = {
                    name: $('.carousel-inner').find('.video-player').attr('id'),
                    id: $(model.container).attr("data-youTubeId"),
                    duration: '',
                    playlistID: model.playlistID
                };

                videoArray.push(videoArrayObject);

                if (typeof videoArray === 'undefined')
                    return;

                var currentPlayer = createPlayer(videoArray[0]);
            };
        };

    /**
     * Returns init
     * @return public methods/functions
     * @public
     */
    return {
        init: init
    };

}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- main slider carousel -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12" id="slider">
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
            <!-- main slider carousel items -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" data-youTubePlaylistId="PLRWIBpSyMDkowgqG8rvNF13GlhlmyPIki">
                <div class="active item carousel-item" data-slide-number="0">
                    <div class="video-wrapper is-loading" data-youTubeId="" vid-height="270" vid-width="480">
                        <div class="video-player" id="ytPlayer"></div>
                        <div class="video-poster" style="background-image:url('https://img.youtube.com/vi/WFpJnRvK6C4/maxresdefault.jpg')">
                            <div class="video-player-content">
                                <h2>Train For Tomorrow HD</h2>
                                <p class="video-duration"></p>
                                <a class="" href="#_">Play video</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="loading-div"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- main slider carousel nav controls -->

            <ul class="carousel-indicators list-inline hidden">
                <li class="list-inline-item active">
                    <a id="carousel-selector-0" class="selected" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel">
                        <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/WFpJnRvK6C4/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="" class="video-poster">
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would really appreciate if anyone can help me get over the line with this one. It's proven to be waaaaay more complicated than what I originally thought!